# xUnit Collection Fixtures not inherited

Tags: xunit

I have a pattern of xunit tests along these lines:

- a test class matching the class being tested
- subclasses for each method being tested
- a fixture to support artifacts needed for the test

```
[Collection("SomeFixture")]
public class SomeClass
{
  public SomeClass(SomeFixture fixture) {}

  public class MethodA: SomeClass
  {
    public MethodA(SomeFixture fixture): base(fixture) {}
    // ...
  }

  public class MethodB: SomeClass
  {
    public MethodB(SomeFixture fixture): base(fixture) {}
    // ...
  }

}
```

> Note that the subclasses do not directly have the `[Collection("SomeFixture")]` attribute; it's inherited.

Today, I updated my projects to `net8.0` including:

- `xunit` from v 2.5.0 to 2.6.3
- `xunit.runner.visualstudio` from v 2.5.0 to 2.5.5

Upon this update, I now get a compiler error:

```
Code: Error xUnit1041   
Description: Fixture argument 'fixture' does not have a fixture source (if it comes from a collection definition, ensure the definition is in the same assembly as the test) (https://xunit.net/xunit.analyzers/rules/xUnit1041)
```

This is easily fixed by copying the `Collection` attribute to each subclass. However, I have hundreds of these tests to do this to.

Is there a way to avoid a tedious copy/paste to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to [roll back to xunit 2.6.2](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/discussions/2847).

[Edit] You can now use the latest version of xunit; the bug has been fixed.